# Prove:$x^2+2xy+3y^2-6x-2y\ge-11\;\;\forall(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}$

Tags: inequality, quadratics

> **Problem Statement:-**
>
> Prove that for all real values of $x$ and $y$
>   $$x^2+2xy+3y^2-6x-2y\ge-11$$

I have no idea how to approach this question all I could think on seeing it was tryin to find the linear factors, turns out that the determinant 
$$\begin{vmatrix}
a & h & g\\
h & b & f\\
g & f & c\\
\end{vmatrix}\neq0$$

So finding linear factor just flew out of the window, so I plotted the equation $x^2+2xy+3y^2-6x-2y=0$ turns out it is an ellipse. I could conclude no further as to how to approach this problem.

Comment: Are you allowed to use derivatives?

Comment: @Sil - Hmm...didn't think about that but does partial derivative w.r.t either of $x$ or $y$ produces the result?

Comment: Try taking derivatives to find extrema (in particular a minimum).

Comment: @user350331 Yes, it reduces to solving $2$ linear equations in $2$ variables.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

We have
$$\begin{align}x^2+2xy+3y^2-6x-2y+11&=x^2+(2y-6)x+3y^2-2y+11\\\\&=(x+y-3)^2-(y-3)^2+3y^2-2y+11\\\\&=(x+y-3)^2+2y^2+4y+2\\\\&=(x+y-3)^2+2(y+1)^2\end{align}$$

Comment: How did you get the third step from second step?

Comment: @tatan: We have $x^2+(2y-6)x=(x+y-3)^2-(y-3)^2$ because $x^2+2Ax=(x^2+2Ax+A^2)-A^2=(x+A)^2-A^2$ where $A=y-3$.

Answer (score 5):

Consider $f(x,y) = x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 -6x -2y + 11 = x^2 + (2y -6)x + (3y^2-2y -11)$ as quadratic polynomial on $x$ variable, then the classic discriminant is
$$ \Delta =-8y^2 -16y -8 < 0 \quad\forall y\in \mathbb{R}/\{-1\}  $$
Thus $f(x,y) > 0 $ for each $y \in \mathbb{R}/\{ -1\}$, now the only case that you should work is for $y=-1$ and this is easy.

Answer (score 3):

Once you can use derivatives this is straightforward:

$$
f_x = 2x+2y-6=0\\
f_y = 2x+6y-2=0
$$

These give you a critical point $(x_0,y_0)=(4,-1)$. You can verify that $f(4,-1)=-11$. It remains to show that this is indeed the minimum (here is where the second derivatives come):

$$
f_{xx} = 2,f_{xy} = 2,f_{yy} = 6
$$

So you have

$$
f_{xx}f_{yy} -f_{xy}^2 = 12-4=8 > 0, f_{xx}>0
$$

and by the [Second Derivative Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test) it is sufficient to conclude that $f(4,-1)=-11$ is indeed the minimum.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(x,y)=x^2+2xy+3y^2-6x-2y$

$$\frac{\partial  f(x,y)}{\partial x}=2x+2y-6=0\\\frac{\partial  f(x,y)}{\partial y}=6y+2x-2=0$$ It is clear that $f(x,y)$ has no maximum. Then the solution of this system $(x,y)=(4,-1)$ gives a minimum. This minimum is precisely
$$f(4,-1)=-11$$

Comment: Can you explain what you have done?

Comment: See at  Sil's solution above and consider that it is obvious that there is no maximum

Comment: I did not understand the second part of his answer

Comment: You actually have a function z = F (x, y) and the criterion of the second derivative applies similarly to when it has a function y = f (x). In this case, when there is, say, a minimum (graphically), you can see that as the variable grows, the value of the derivative (i.e. the value of the tangent) goes from zero (at the extreme point) to a positive value, that is, the derivative is increasing. Something similar is given for the function z = F (x, y). Now if you are "inspired" it would be better to look at Mathlove's answer above. Sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 0):

The matrix for the quadratic form is
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -3 \\
1 & 3 & -1 \\
-3 & -1 & 11
\end{bmatrix}
$$
A sufficient condition for the quadratic form to be positive semidefinite is that the leading principal minors but the last (that ought to be nonnegative) are positive. If also the full determinant is positive, the matrix is positive definite.

The leading principal minors are
$$
\det[1]=1,
\qquad
\det\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & 3\end{bmatrix}=2,
\qquad
\det A=0
$$
Thus $A$ is a positive semidefinite symmetric matrix and thus $v^TAv\ge0$ for all $v\in\mathbb{R}^3$, in particular for $v=[x\;y\;1]^T$, which proves the thesis.

The null space can be determined by Gaussian elimination:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -3 \\
1 & 3 & -1 \\
-3 & -1 & 11
\end{bmatrix}
&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -3 \\
0 & 2 & 2 \\
0 & 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}&&R_2\gets R_2-R_1, R_3\gets R_3+3R_1
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -3 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}&&R_2\gets \tfrac{1}{2}R_2
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & -3 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}&&R_3\gets R_3-2R_2
\\&\to
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -4 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}&&R_1\gets R_1-R_2
\end{align}
So an eigenvector for the zero eigenvalue is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}4 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}
$$
and, indeed, the point with coordinates $(4,-1)$ is the only one where the form vanishes.